# How to store sensitive data in react js frontend?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, local-storage

I want to clear this issue. I'm new to react js. but I need to store some sensitive data in frontend. just like database name, database password, and database username. I have used **universal-cookie** and **local storage** also. but it seems like not secure. because anyone can edit that data if they inspect the page and open the cookie tab. I just want to know if there is a way to make these **cookies uneditable** or suggest to me if there is a **better way** to keep this data in frontend?

Thanks in advance

[image: i have edited the access token and dbname for testing]

Comment: Cookies and server side validation. You shouldn't store sensitive data in your client. Use the server-side session storage.

Comment: These secret are better placed within `.env`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman but the problem is this one is a login system. if the user entered the password and user code. first, it will send the API request to my master database and it will take the database user name ..etc according to the user code. so i need to keep that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally sensitive data are not saving on frontend.
best way is you can call this from server using http request.
Or you can use local storage,cookies,session storage etc.
env setup is another way.
Or you can use thirdparty storge for this, many free & trusted resources are available

Comment: if I set environment variable. can I update that using syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you do not want to, you should always send it encrypted from your BE> But if you must you can create a .env.local file at the root of your react project and put all your variables there. The variable names should start REACT_APP. there should be NO space/quotations around your values in this file

```
REACT_APP_DB_PASS=your_pass
REACT_APP_DB_ID=your_id
```

and then you can access them from the process.env object like this

```js
process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASS
```

Comment: can I change these values ??

Comment: @Ranushkakalhara Yes, when you change the values on the `.env` file.

Comment: which values, the values would your actual password and id. The variables name just have to start with React_App, rest can be whatever. Remember to put this file in your .gitignore, or  similar file if you are using a differnet version control software than git

Comment: @ssaquif the actual thing is this one is a login system. if the user entered the password and user code. first, it will send the API request to my master database and it will take the database user name ..etc according to the user code. so I need to keep that data. so I cant initialize this data